# Improvement of a SliceCountorPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am trying to get a high quality SliceCountorPlot3D with the following code

```
SliceContourPlot3D[((
   2 E^(2 Re[-((p1 + x0)^2/(
         2 (E^(-2 Subscript[r, 1]) + 2 E^(-2 Subscript[r, 2])))) + 
        Subscript[r, 1]] + 
     1/4 E^(Subscript[r, 1] + Subscript[r, 2]) (p1 + x0)^2 Sech[
       Subscript[r, 1] - Subscript[r, 2]] - Subscript[r, 1]) Sqrt[
    E^(2 Subscript[r, 1]) + E^(2 Subscript[r, 2])])/(
   2 E^(2 Subscript[r, 1]) + E^(2 Subscript[r, 2]))) /. {x0 -> 0, 
   Subscript[r, 1] -> r1, 
   Subscript[r, 2] -> r2}, "CenterCutBox", {r1, -1, 1}, {r2, -1, 
  1}, {p1, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

and Mathematica gives the following result:

[image]

Which shows irregular lines on the sides of the Plot. Then, my question is:

**What do I have to add to my code to remove these irregular lines and get a better image quality?**

Answer (score 7):

Add the option `BoundaryStyle -> None`:

```
SliceContourPlot3D[expr, "CenterCutBox", 
 {r1, -1, 1}, {r2, -1, 1}, {p1, -5, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]