# Spurious output from SliceDensityPlot3D with CenterCutBox

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.2 or earlier, persisting through 13.2.**

---

I am modeling a simple system: the potential from a sphere of charge Q as a function of position.  SliceDensityPlot3D with the "CenterCutBox" option *almost* gives a gorgeous output, and except for the clutter on the right facing surfaces it does exactly what I want: gives a sense of the potential both on the surface and interior to the cube.  I have tried different PlotPoints, to no avail.

In the SliceDensityPlot3D documentation under "scope -> surfaces -> Standard boundary surfaces" a table with the three boundary surfaces is provided, and which looks fine in the documentation page (no surprise).  When I use the exact same code in my own notebook, I get the same spurious output (!).

As another try, I used a cylinder, however I could not get that to appear smooth and also there is no centercut cylinder.

I am running version 12.2.0.0 on Win 10 pro.  Thanks in advance!

```
a = 5 10^-5; 
q1 = 1.602 * 10^-12;
eps0 = 8.85418781 * 10^-12; 
qEnclosed1[r_] := If[r < a, (q1 r^3)/a^3, q1];
eField1[r_] := qEnclosed1[r]/(4 \[Pi] r^2 eps0);
potSphereTEMP[r_] = -Integrate[eField1[r], r ];
potInfinity = Limit[potSphereTEMP[r], {r -> \[Infinity]} ];
potSphere[r_] := potSphereTEMP[r] - potInfinity 
potSphereCartesian[x_, y_, z_] := potSphere[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 potSphereCartesian[x, y, z], "CenterCutBox" , {x, -3.0 a, 
  0.0 a}, {y, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, {z, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] (* my plot *)

SliceDensityPlot3D[potSphereCartesian[x, y, z], 
 Cylinder[{{-3. a, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}}, a], {x, -3.0 a, 
  0.0 a}, {y, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, {z, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Method -> {"CylinderPoints" -> {200, 
     200}}]  (* another version of my plot *)

Table[SliceDensityPlot3D[Sin[x] + y^2 - z^3, 
  sl, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> sl], {sl, {"CenterSphere", "CenterCutSphere", 
   "CenterCutBox"}}]  (* copied direction from documentation *)
```

[image: Output from main part of the notebook]

Comment: `BoundaryStyle -> None`.

Comment: This is a confirmed bug. (I mean the output of `CenterCutBox`. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with the `Cylinder` surface can be fixed using exact numbers:

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[potSphereCartesian[x, y, z], 
 Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {-3 a, 0, 0}}, a], 
 {x, -3 a, 0}, {y, -3/2 a, 3/2 a}, {z, -3/2 a, 3/2 a}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Method -> {"CylinderPoints" -> {200, 200}}]
```

[image]

The issue with `"CenterCutBox"` can be fixed using `BoundaryStyle -> None` (as in [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284949/125)):

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 potSphereCartesian[x, y, z], "CenterCutBox",
 {x, -3.0 a, 0.0 a}, {y, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, {z, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[Sin[x] + y^2 - z^3, "CenterCutBox",
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: This got me going again, @kglr, thanks so much.  My only question, really out of curiosity more than necessity, is why I need to add "BoundaryStyle -> None" and that is not included in the docs.  May there is a background setting I am not using?

Comment: @JackAdams, I could not find any reference in the docs either. I found by accident (using `BoundaryStyle->Green`)  that those spurious lines are boundary lines.